# How can I get general solution $y(x)$ in next differential equation : $(1+ xy)dx + (1-xy)dy = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used mathematica, and got solution, but that solution was too dirty and including lots of hard functions.
Is there any way to get solution for this equation -

$$(1+ xy)dx + (1-xy)dy = 0$$

Comment: the solution of this equation can not be found in the known elementary functions

Comment: this is known under the Name Abel equation

Answer (score 0):

Approach $1$:

$(1+xy)~dx+(1-xy)~dy=0$

$(xy-1)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=xy+1$

$\left(y-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y+\dfrac{1}{x}$

Let $u=y-\dfrac{1}{x}$ ,

Then $y=u+\dfrac{1}{x}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)=u+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)u+\dfrac{2}{x}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Approach $2$:

$(1+xy)~dx+(1-xy)~dy=0$

$(xy+1)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=xy-1$

$\left(x+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=x-\dfrac{1}{y}$

Let $u=x+\dfrac{1}{y}$ ,

Then $x=u-\dfrac{1}{y}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}\right)=u-\dfrac{1}{y}-\dfrac{1}{y}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{y^2}\right)u-\dfrac{2}{y}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.